# WordPress with Yahoo! Hosting... Almost there

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, yahoo, root, permalinks

**EDIT:**

Yeah, so this problem is really unsolvable.  Yahoo prevents access to .htaccess, even from WordPress itself trying to change it.  I had to settle for writing a script on the default homepage that redirects browsers to "www.abc.com/index.php" if they go straight to "www.abc.com".  You always have to deal with "index.php" being in the address bar but it's better than not having permalinks...

**/EDIT**

Yahoo! Small Business hosting seems specifically engineered to make WordPress difficult-- but it's my client's host and there's not much I can do about it.  I'm trying to move WordPress into the root directory, and I'm sooo close to having it done.

I've read and read and read about how to get the Permalinks to work right, and since Yahoo! hosting doesn't let you modify htaccess I am pretty much up s*** creek.  I'm using the simple permalink structure of "/%postname%/", which once I moved to the root, stopped working.  I have changed it to "/index.php/%postname%/", which allows you to see the pages if you manually type in index.php before the page name or if you are logged into the admin area and "View Page".  Also, the correct permalink shows on all of the pages in the editor.

However, WordPress doesn't let you change the permalink of the static page you use as the front page.

Long story short, if I go to "www.abc.com/index.php", the links in the menu all work fine.  However, if I just got to "www.abc.com", the links don't pick up the "index.php" from the permalink structure.  I need to fix this, so if anyone knows how to either:

1. Change the permalink of the static front page
2. Fix something in the database if I install PhpMyAdmin
3. Work around not having access to .htaccess
4. Put a small script somewhere on the index page to append "index.php" to the url
5. Any other suggestions

It seems it would work if I was NOT using a static front page but rather the blog, but this isn't an option.  I've tried changing the "Tag base" setting to no avail, as well as deactivating the Yahoo! Custom Permalinks plugin (and reactivating it again after that failed...).  Could really use some help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [***Giving Wordpress its own directory***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). I can see how this could solve your problem.  Also make sure that you have done the obvious, and change your url for WordPress address (URL) Site address (URL) inside the general settings page.  Perhaps the static homepage should be developed outside of wordpress, and then you can follow the steps provided in the link I provided.  Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo doesn't allow users access to the htaccess file which means that you can't the mod_rewrite rules needed for custom permlinks. The Only way around it that i've heard it works (never tried it myself) is to add `/index.php/` to the beginning of your custom structure so: Go to Permalink Settings > Select Custom Structure. And set the value as `/index.php/%postname%/` or what ever you want as long as you add /index.php/ before it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this host (in 2018! 4 years after your question) that I finally solved by changing the permalink settings.

```
Settings > Permalink Settings > Custom Structure: /index.php/%postname%/
```

I wish there was a better solution but Yahoo Small Business still doesn't allow `.htaccess` files - after several frustrating rounds with customer service, I finally admitted defeat and used this work around.